# this code is not working (woocomcer thankyou page)

Tags: php, woocommerce

m trying to add this code via custom plugin, and trying to hook on woocomrce thankyou page, but its not working

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'snd_thankyou_page' );
 
function snd_thankyou_page() {
    $allOrderValue = $order->get_total();
    $allOrdrId = $order->get_order_number();
    $allEmailNew = $order->get_billing_email();
   ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        dataLayer.push({
        'event':'ec_purchase',
        'order_value': '<?php echo $allOrderValue ?>',
        'order_id': '<?php echo $allOrdrId ?>',
        'enhanced_conversion_data': { "email": '<?php echo $allEmailNew ?>'  }
      })
    </script>   
   <?php
}
```

Comment: [*It's not working*](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forgot to pass $order_id to your function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'snd_thankyou_page' );
 
function snd_thankyou_page( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $allOrderValue = $order->get_total();
    $allOrdrId = $order->get_order_number();
    $allEmailNew = $order->get_billing_email();
   ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        dataLayer.push({
        'event':'ec_purchase',
        'order_value': '<?php echo $allOrderValue ?>',
        'order_id': '<?php echo $allOrdrId ?>',
        'enhanced_conversion_data': { "email": '<?php echo $allEmailNew ?>'  }
      })
    </script>   
   <?php
}
```